# how do I print the number of elements

Tags: xml, perl

following is my code which will return name of the units. 
but how do I count and print the number of units using perl?
basically printing the number of elements which contains unit tag?
Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use XML::DOM;

my $parser = new XML::DOM::Parser;
my $dom_obj;

die "Unable to parse XML document\n" 
    unless $dom_obj = $parser->parsefile("course.xml");

my @nodes = $dom_obj->getElementsByTagName("unit");

foreach my $elem (@nodes)
{
    if ($elem->getNodeType == ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
        print $elem->getTagName, "\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the number of elements in an array, evaluate the array in scalar context.

```
print(scalar(@nodes), "\n");
```

or

```
print(0+@nodes, "\n");
```

or

```
print(@nodes . "\n");
```